# NaN value same as delimiter - how do I import?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, import, format

I am trying to import the USDA's SR28 nutrition data into python using read_csv from pandas.

The data is described as this:

```
ASCII files are delimited. All fields are separated by carets (^) and text fields are
surrounded by tildes (~). A double caret (^^) or two carets and two tildes (~~) appear
when a field is null or blank.
```

I don't know how to handle the double caret nulls. Many of the rows have five or six blank fields in a row leading to '^^^^^^^^^^' in my row. I end up with far too many columns, throwing the table off.

So far I have tried this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('.../NUT_DATA.txt', sep="^", na_values=["~~","^^"], header=None)
print(data[0:3])
```

From that I get the improper breakout of columns. I am not familiar enough with regex to try and exclude double carets from the seperator, but even then I don't know how I would manage to differentiate when a carrot is part of a double or the delimiter for the next column.

Sample of the raw USDA data:

```
~01001~^~268~^2999^0^^~4~^~NC~^~~^~~^^^^^^^~~^09/2015^
~01001~^~269~^0.06^0^^~4~^~NR~^~~^~~^^^^^^^~~^11/2002^
~01001~^~291~^0.0^0^^~4~^~~^~~^~~^^^^^^^~~^^
~01001~^~301~^24^17^0.789^~1~^~A~^~~^~~^7^19^30^4^22.021^26.496^~2, 3~^11/2002^
~01001~^~303~^0.02^18^0.011^~1~^~A~^~~^~~^7^0.00^0.15^7^-0.008^0.046^~2, 3~^03/2003^
~01001~^~304~^2^18^0.047^~1~^~A~^~~^~~^7^1^2^4^1.586^1.863^~2, 3~^03/2003^
~01001~^~305~^24^17^0.463^~1~^~A~^~~^~~^7^19^27^7^22.488^24.653^~2, 3~^03/2003^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `quotechar='~'`

```
pd.read_csv('.../NUT_DATA.txt', sep='^', quotechar='~', header=None)

     0    1        2   3      4   5    6   7   8    9     10     11   12      13      14    15       16  17
0  1001  268  2999.00   0    NaN   4   NC NaN NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN  09/2015 NaN
1  1001  269     0.06   0    NaN   4   NR NaN NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN  11/2002 NaN
2  1001  291     0.00   0    NaN   4  NaN NaN NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN      NaN NaN
3  1001  301    24.00  17  0.789   1    A NaN NaN  7.0  19.0  30.00  4.0  22.021  26.496  2, 3  11/2002 NaN
4  1001  303     0.02  18  0.011   1    A NaN NaN  7.0   0.0   0.15  7.0  -0.008   0.046  2, 3  03/2003 NaN
5  1001  304     2.00  18  0.047   1    A NaN NaN  7.0   1.0   2.00  4.0   1.586   1.863  2, 3  03/2003 NaN
6  1001  305    24.00  17  0.463   1    A NaN NaN  7.0  19.0  27.00  7.0  22.488  24.653  2, 3  03/2003 NaN
```

`fillna` if you'd like

```
pd.read_csv('.../NUT_DATA.txt', sep='^', quotechar='~', header=None).fillna('')

     0    1        2   3      4   5   6  7  8  9   10    11 12      13      14    15       16 17
0  1001  268  2999.00   0          4  NC                                              09/2015   
1  1001  269     0.06   0          4  NR                                              11/2002   
2  1001  291     0.00   0          4                                                            
3  1001  301    24.00  17  0.789   1   A        7  19    30  4  22.021  26.496  2, 3  11/2002   
4  1001  303     0.02  18  0.011   1   A        7   0  0.15  7  -0.008   0.046  2, 3  03/2003   
5  1001  304     2.00  18  0.047   1   A        7   1     2  4   1.586   1.863  2, 3  03/2003   
6  1001  305    24.00  17  0.463   1   A        7  19    27  7  22.488  24.653  2, 3  03/2003
```

Comment: If you don't mind my asking... what is quotechar's purpose?

Comment: Ah! I didn't need to specify na_values, because the '~~' is the equivalent of ',,' in a typical csv. In my mind, I saw the equiv of ',,' being '~~~~' for some reason. And the quotechar lets read_csv know the tilde marks strings. I think.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `quotechar` specifies the character in which text is expected to be wrapped in.